# Why does coarray with allocatable component creates segmentation faults when accessed from different image?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran-coarrays

I want to use the fortran coarray feature to have different size arrays on different images.

Following the 2008/2018 standard, this should be possible by using a derived type containing an allocatable. I am using gfortran 8.2.0 with opencoarrays 2.3.1.1 MPI library on macOS Mojave.

```
program Main
    implicit none

    type :: Array_Type
        double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: values
    end type
    type(Array_Type), codimension[*] :: array

    if(this_image() == 1) then
        allocate(array%values(2))
        array%values = this_image()
    else
        allocate(array%values(1))
    endif
    sync all

    print *, this_image(), array[1]%values(:)
    sync all
end program
```

The program is compiled by

```
gfortran -Wall -fcoarray=lib Main.f90 -lcaf_mpi
```

An even simpler example leads to the same segmentation fault when the allocated array is accessed by other images.

```
program Main
    implicit none

    type :: Array_Type
        double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: values
    end type
    type(Array_Type), codimension[*] :: array

    allocate(array%values(2))
    sync all

    print *, this_image(), array[1]%values(:)
    sync all
end program
```

Comment: I would file an issue in the OpenCoarray github. Either it is a bug and they should know about it or you will get a qualified explanation. Your codes works for me with Intel Fortran 16.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What's the expected behavior for the print statement in the second code block? Isn't `array[1]%values` undefined when it's not yet assigned a value?

Comment: @A. Hennonk: It is not initialized, but the space in memory is defined. It might contain any value, but for printing the value is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

The code works correctly with the specified system as long as MPICH instead of the default OpenMpi is used with OpenCoarrays.

Additionally, the OpenCoarrays compiler wrapper should be used: `caf Main.f90`

I opened an issue at the OpenCoarrays GitHub site: https://github.com/sourceryinstitute/OpenCoarrays/issues/625